# Android SDK Multiple Buttons

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

Does anyone know how to add multiple buttons in android that will allow a user to select one that will go to a coresponding page? I know this is a rather broad question. I can code one button and it's fine, but if I when I try coding a second or third button, I'm running into problems.

```
 btn 1 = football
 btn 2 = baseball
 btn 3= soccer
 btn 4= rugby
 btn5 = hockey
```

How do I code this so let's say a user selects soccer, that will then take a user to a page that I named soccer? Just two coded buttons will do. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

add onclick listener to all buttons and start new activity by using intent.
  button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FirstActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

});
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Secondactivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

});
button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Third.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

});
button4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Fourth.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

});

Comment: Welcome..:) .If your problem is solved, then please close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way will be doing like this

```
    football_button.setOnClickListener(buttonListeners);
    baseball_button.setOnClickListener(buttonListeners);


OnClickListener buttonListeners = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.football_button:  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Football.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        break;
        case R.id.baseball_button:          Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Baseball.class);
        startActivity(intent);
                                        break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Should be the other way around, setting click listener AFTER declaring the listener ...